# Is there a simple tool or a library for “rolling up” a set of events with timestamps into a count of events in each time window of a given span?

Tags: events, rollup

My specific problem is that I have a set of Apache access logs, and I want to extract from them a “rolled up” count of requests by grouping them into a set of time windows of a specified time.

Example of my data:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:11 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 304 266 "-" "Sosospider+(+http://help.soso.com/webspider.htm)"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:24 -0500] "GET /feed/rss2/ HTTP/1.0" 301 447 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=12878631678486589417)"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:25 -0500] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.0" 304 189 "-" "Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html; 1 subscribers; feed-id=12878631678486589417)"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:30 -0500] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 333 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ScoutJet; +http://www.scoutjet.com/)"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2011:00:00:30 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 10011 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; ScoutJet; +http://www.scoutjet.com/)"
```

as you can see, each line represents an event — in this case, a HTTP request — and contains a timestamp.

Assuming my data covers 3 days, and I specify a time window size of 1 day, I’d like to generate something like this:

```
Start    End     Count
2011-12-01 05:00     2011-12-02 05:00    2822
2011-12-02 05:00     2011-12-03 05:00    2572
2011-12-03 05:00     2011-12-04 05:00    604
```

But I need to be able to vary the size of the window — I might want to analyze a given dataset using windows of 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day, or 1 week, etc.

I also need the library/tool to be capable of analyzing a dataset (a series of lines) of hundreds or even thousands of megabytes in size.

A prebuilt tool which can accept the data via standard input would be great, but a library would be totally fine, as I could just build the tool around the library. Any language would be fine; if I don’t know it I can learn it.

I’d prefer to do this by piping the access log data directly into a tool/library with minimal dependencies — I’m not looking for suggestions to store the data in a database and then query the database to do the analysis. If I need to, I can figure that out myself.

I tried Splunk and found it way too heavyweight and complex for my case. It’s not just a tool, it’s a whole system with its own datastore, complex indexing and querying abilities, etc.

My question is: does such a library and/or tool exist?

#### Full disclosure

I must admit, I actually tried and failed to find something like this a few months ago, so I wrote my own. For some reason I didn’t think to post this question at that time. I will share the lib/tool I wrote in an answer shortly. But I really am curious if something like this does exist; maybe I just missed it when I was searching a few months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, I actually attempted a few months ago, unsuccessfully, to find something like this, so I wrote my own. (For some reason I didn’t think to post this question at that time.)

I took this as an opportunity to learn functional programming (FP) and to shore up my proficiency with CoffeeScript. So I wrote [Rollups](https://github.com/aviflax/rollups) as a [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) tool which runs on [Node](http://nodejs.org). I’ve since added [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) versions, as part of my further exploration of FP.

All the versions are intended to be usable as both a tool and a library, although they’re all only part of the way towards that — I think currently only the Clojure version is truly safe to use as a library, and I haven’t tested it that way.

The tools work as I described in my question. Given a file or set of files containing Apache access logs, I invoke them like so:

```
$ gzcat *.access.log.gz | rollup.clj -w 1d
```

(or `rollup.coffee`, `rollup.scala`) and the output is exactly like the example in the question.

This tool solved my problem, and I’m no longer actively using it on a day-to-day basis. But I’d love to improve it further for others’ use, if I knew that others were using it. So feedback would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Splunk (http://www.splunk.com/) would be the tool I think of for a problem like this.  It's available in free and paid versions; I have not licensed it myself, just used it already installed.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried Splunk and found it way too heavyweight and complex for my taste. It’s not just a tool, it’s a whole system with its own datastore, complex indexing and querying abilities, etc. I’ll update my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So, how automatic does this have to be? Can I give a not-really answer that is still useful?

If you wanted to be really ghetto about it, what I usually do is end up one-offing an ugly bunch of shell. Here's one that will sum by hour using some `cut` tricks and `awk` (which I'm admittedly not very good at but is incredibly fast and powerful).

```
cat access_log | cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d ':' -f 1,2 | awk '{ date=$1; if (date==olddate) sum=sum+1; else { if (olddate!="") {print olddate,sum}; olddate=date; sum=1}} END {print date,sum}'
```

([This post on plotting with awk](http://hblok.net/blog/posts/2011/04/29/analysing-apache-logs-gnuplot-and-awk/) helped me figure out the aggregation bit.)

That should output something like:

```
12/Apr/2012:11 207
12/Apr/2012:12 188
12/Apr/2012:13 317
```

Which can be pretty easily played with itself. Awk is neat.

Comment: Agreed that this isn’t really answering my question, but still a neat technique. Thanks!